# Tomcat shutdown due to flow control mechanism of active mq

Tags: java, activemq-classic, tomcat8

We have an application that is deployed on a tomcat server.
The application produces and consumes messages on an activemq server.

We had an issue recently that caused triggered flow control on active mq message producers due to 100% store percent used. (http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html)

Somehow this cause our applciations on tomcat servers to shutdown.

> INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.

It seems something triggered a graceful shutdown, but I'm not sure how it's connected to the activemq issue. But the shutdown issue was resolved when we resolved the active mq issue.

How are these connected?

Could it be that the producer control flow caused jms connections to pile up causing the tomcat server to shutdown itself?